# Google Docs script giving unspecified error - Unsure of cause

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I'm new to Google Docs scripting, and am following [this tutorial](https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2020/09/29/auto-fill-a-google-doc-template-from-google-sheet-data) in order to create Google docs from a template and a Google sheet. I've written everything as the tutorial specifies - here's the entirety of my code:

```
function onOpen() {
  const menu =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Create Review Forms');
  menu.addItem('Create Review Forms', 'createNewGoogleDocs');
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1JqwXS_yOo_v2CV5akOf26tQnj-AdB3cvrVmxTn10lZI');
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1ZFaHXonRQZ-2S5YGj5vCRu_r23vWoVod');
  const rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(rows)

  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
    if (index === 0) return;
    if (row[6]) return;
    const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]} ${row[2]} application`, destinationFolder);
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
    const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText('{{Cand Number}}', row[0]);
    body.replaceText('{{Resume}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Essay 1}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Essay 2}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Essay 3}}', row[4]);

    doc.saveAndClose();
    sheet.getDataRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(doc.getUrl());
  })
}
```

It works insofar as a menu option is created as specified in the onOpen function. However, every time I try to run or debug the whole thing, I get this "Unknown error" in the execution log:

[image: Unknown Error]

This started even after I wrote the first couple of lines in the lower function, but even when I comment them out the Unknown Error persists. I'd appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `However, every time I try to run or debug the whole thing, I get this "Unknown error" in the execution log:`? How did you run your script?

Comment: There's a "Run" button right above the script. I can also select the particular function I run.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `There's a "Run" button right above the script. I can also select the particular function I run.`, about `However, every time I try to run or debug the whole thing, I get this "Unknown error" in the execution log:`, in this case, when you run `createNewGoogleDocs()` with the custom menu, no error occurs. But. you run it with "Run" button of the script editor, the error shown in your question occurs. Is my understanding correct?